# Example Usage of Threading in Python 2.1

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I need some help implementing threading using Python 2.1. I would readily update to a newer version of Python, but unfortunately, I'm working within an interpreter built into a video game, so 2.1 is written in stone for me. To be clear, I need an example of how to do threading without using 'import threading'. 'import thread' is okay, but I can't get it to work right; usually it just locks up the game, when I try to spawn a new thread.

Alternatively, if someone could kindly explain to me where I might find this core 'threading' module, I might be able to incorporate that into a solution, because the examples I've read about how to use that module seem very straight-forward.

TIA

Comment: Python 2.1????? We are at Python 2.7!

Comment: If using threads locks up the system, it's quite possible that the system was never intended to use threads and has some bug preventing it from working.

Comment: 2.7 is the latest of the 2.X line

Comment: Gabe makes a good point. Are you sure it's a real implementation of the thread module and not just dummy_thread? What is the underlying platform? Do you know anything about this particular Python?

Comment: Yea, yea ... I know it's older than dirt, but work with me here. I'm afraid that Gabe is right, but I want to exhaust my possibilities before reaching that conclusion. I did at one point, get it to work to some extent, but I was getting really mixed results. Things were happening out of order. I read somewhere that Python doesn't support real threading, and so a 'thread' actually executes an arbitrary amount of byte code as it switches between 'threads'. Is that true? Also, what other information about Python would you need to know to help me?

Comment: Python supports threads, it just can't execute them simultaneously (even if you have multiple CPUs). Each thread holds a global interpreter lock (GIL) for so many bytecodes before releasing it and letting another thread get it. Note that the lock is not held while running non-Python code like system calls and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `threading` module. If you don't have it, you can get the version from Python 2.1 here: http://pastebin.com/5f9NBmcg

Note that it imports `thread`, so if your system has a problem with threads, it still won't work.

If you need specific modules from Python 2.1, go to the [release page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.1.3/) and click on one of the download links:

- [Python-2.1.3.tgz](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.1.3/Python-2.1.3.tgz) - you can use `gunzip`, then `tar` to extract the files
- [Python-2.1.3.exe](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.1.3/Python-2.1.3.exe) - you can rename the file to put a `.zip` extentsion on it, then use your favorite ZIP utility to extract files.

Comment: Any chance you have the StringIO module? That's absent in 2.1 too. Or better yet, tell me where I might find other modules like that, in case I start digging a deeper rabbit hole, here.

Comment: OK, I put instructions on how to find get all the source code for Python 2.1.3 (the latest version of 2.1).

Comment: Well, it worked .. kind of. I installed that threading module, and its dependencies, and it surprisingly, worked just fine. However, there must be some limit the game is putting on things, maybe the amount of memory the interpreter can consume. I can only open so many threads before the game freezes, and that number of thread varies depending on the amount of processing each thread does. With my original intentions, I can't even open one thread before things crash. Oh well, good effort, and thanks for the help!